# USB to Ethernet Adapter

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running right now and for some reason when I go to network I don't see the option for USB -> Ethernet like I do on my new version of Ubuntu. 
This box plays a major roll in production and I don't want to have to upgrade or rebuild. Is there a driver or package that I can install in order to get USB -> Ethernet working for this distro of Ubuntu? Please advise on what I can do.

thank you,

Comment: When doing a dmesg |grep usb I do see the following [  416.316430] asix 1-4:1.0 eth0: register 'asix' at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:bf:3f:07

Comment: How about: `dmesg | grep asix` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this distro not support usb -> ethernet adapters? My 18.04 work fine with the adapters....

Comment: It sure should support it. Is the dmesg you posted that mentions `asix` from the 18.04 installation or from 16.04? We hope it is 16.04 as it is always easier to diagnose in the installation where it does *not* work.

Comment: The dmesg is from 16.04 it does not even give me the options under networking for USB -> Ethernet on version 18.04 under network you have that option.

Comment: I have upgraded yesterday to 18.04 because of time constraint and I now see the option and have it configured with it pinging the device that I need it to connect to, Here is the version I am on now...

 lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: So the upgrade solved the question? Are you all set?